# Is there a way to shift highlighted lines left or right in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In the Eclipse IDE (and many others I would imagine) there is a simple shortcut to shift highlighted lines either right or left by one tab length.

I have looked through all of the TextFX in Notepad++ and only found the ability to shift highlighted lines up or down. Is there a built in way to shift highlighted lines left or right?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Shift highlighted lines to the right one tab length by pressing the tab key.  Shift them to the left by pressing shift-tab.

When lines are highlighted, the tab key doesn't replace them with a tab.  It shifts them left/right instead.

Comment: Thank you, I feel rather foolish for not trying that myself. I figured that highliting and hitting tab would replace them with a tab as you said.

Answer (score 9):

Tab indents, shift-tab unindents.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following keys to move set of lines of code to forward and backwards

**Right Move:**

```
tab
```

**Left Move:**

```
shift+tab
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Do you just mean that you want to select a region of your code in Notepad++ and intend or unindent it all by a certain number of tabs?

If so, it's really easy.  Just select the lines you want to indent and hit `<tab>`.  All of the lines will indent by 1 tab.  I believe `<shift>+<tab>` will do the opposite.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without tab? Just like the eclipse short cut?